# A non-zero function on $\mathbb{R}^n$ whose integral over any ball of radius $1$ is zero?

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Does there exist a measurable function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, for some $n>1$, which is not equal to $0$ almost everywhere such that for any ball $B$ of radius exactly $1$ we have
$$\int_Bfd\mu=0,$$
where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$?

**Motivation:**
In my original thought, I substituted the shape of ball with another (fixed) convex shape and I let this integral rule hold for all these shapes and at all scales. I proved that in that case the only function is that which is equal to $0$ a.e. My goal was to restrict this integral rule to shapes of the scale equal to $1$ only, but then I figured that it is not enough to conclude $f=0$ a.e. if we took the hypercube to be our convex shape, for example. I was then wondering, does for any shape there exist a counter-example? That's my question reduced to the case when the shape is the ball.

The solution for the case when $B$'s are the cubes of side length $2$:
$$f(x)=-1+2\bigg(\Big(\sum_{k=1}^n\lfloor x_k\rfloor\Big)\;\text{mod}\;2\bigg),$$
where $\lfloor x_k\rfloor$ is the floor of the $k$-th coordinate of $x$.

Comment: For $n=1$, $cos(\pi x)$ qualifies, right? But it's a lot more interesting in $n>1$

Comment: For any $n$ and convex body $K \in \mathbb{R}^n$, if you can find a $k \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\int_K e^{ik\cdot x} d\mu = 0$, then any function of the form $\Re(A e^{ik\cdot x})$ will work.

Comment: @SangchulLee Oops, thanks for catching that. Deleting...

Comment: @AlexK Yes, exactly. The case $n=1$ is not interesting because any convex shape is similar to any other, which includes hypercubes...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For unit ball $B = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n : |x| \le 1 \}$, the answer is YES.

In general, for any $n > 1$ and convex body $K \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ (convex, compact, non-empty interior).
If one can find a $k \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that

$$\int_K e^{ik\cdot x} d\mu = 0$$
then for all function of the form
$f(x) = \Re(A e^{ik\cdot x})$ where $A$ is a constant and translated copy of $K$:
$K_t = \{ x + t : x \in K \}$, we have

$$\int_{K_t} f(x) d\mu = \int_K f(x+t) d\mu
= \Re\left(A e^{ik\cdot t} \int_K e^{ik\cdot x} d\mu\right) = 0$$

Back to the original problem where $K = B$. Using rotation and reflection symmetry,
it just suffices to search for a $k \in (0,\infty)$ such that

$$\int_0^1 \cos(kx) (1-x^2)^{\frac{n-1}{2}} dx = 0\tag{*1}$$

Recall following integral representation of Bessel function${}^{\color{blue}{[1]}}$:

$$J_{\nu}(z) = \frac{2(z/2)^\nu}{\pi^{1/2}\Gamma(\nu + \frac12)} \int_0^1 (1 - t^2)^{\nu-\frac12}\cos(zt)dt$$

Condition $(*1)$ is equivalent to $J_{\frac{n}{2}}(k) = 0$.

Notice for fixed $\nu$ and $x \to \infty$, we have following asymptotic behaviour
${}^{\color{blue}{[2]}}$:

$$J_{\nu}(x) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi x}}\left[\cos\left(x - \frac{\nu}{2}\pi - \frac14\pi\right) + o(1)\right]$$
This means $J_{\frac{n}{2}}(z)$ vanishes infinitely many often on $(0,\infty)$, so we have tons of $k$ to satisfy $(*1)$.

**Notes**

- $\color{blue}{[1]}$ - see $\S 10.9.4$ on [DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.9).
- $\color{blue}{[2]}$ - see $\S 10.7.8$ on [DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.7).

Comment: Can you please just explain what exactly $k\cdot x$ and $e^{ik\cdot x}$ means?

Comment: @donaastor it is the ordinary inner product. ie. if $k = (k_1,\ldots,k_n)$ and $x = (x_1,\ldots,x_n)$, then $k\cdot x = k_1x_1 + \cdots  + k_nx_n$.

Comment: Oh ok, I see, thanks.

Comment: Amazing soluton! Thank you! Btw, since such $f$ exists, the answer is actually YES, i.e. there DOES exist such a functio $f$.

Comment: @donaastor oops, fixed that.

Comment: Also, this means that if the projection of my shape $K$ on some line (calculating the area of intersection of $K$ with hyperplanes normal to the line) is a function whose Fourier transform is purely complex for some frequency, then there is such a function. Then the Bessel function explains that it is the case for $K$ being a ball. Nice!

Answer (score 3):

For $n=1$ take the function

$$\int_{B}\sin(\pi x)\:d\mu = 0$$

for all balls of radius $1$ in $\Bbb{R}$

Comment: @RobertShore a ball of radius $1$ is an interval of length $2$

Comment: Thank you for answering, however I cannot accept it as an answer because I already wrote in motivation section that hypercubes, which includes intervals, do not work.

Comment: He is not saying that it is wrong, just off-topic as the OP already wrote that he understood that it fails for hypercubes. I feel that it was a fair comment to make.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez No, it is right, but I didn't mean to hear this solution. It is not interesting and I have listed it myself. I am sorry for not excluding it in my question originally. I edited now, so this doesn't count anymore, technically.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Already before the editing the OP mentions that he understands that hypercubes don't work. In any case it is nice to mention that $n>1$ is the relevant case :)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Can't I take a function on the unit cube with vanishing integral and look at the periodic extension to get a counterexample?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez, I did not want to throw all the formalities with the complete back-story of the problem, I wanted to make it clear and easy and quick to understand. It is my mistake that I forgot the detail that $n>1$. In any case, the point of my question was to inspire some exploration, not to obtain a formally correct solution. To be clear about what hypercubes make: For any $n$ and any shape $F$ that is a parallelotope, there exists a function $f$ which is never equal to zero, such that the integral over all translations of $F$ is $0$.